# How to upload any file in android

Tags: android, post, file-upload

I want to develop an android app for upload all type of file to server. But code is for only upload image file. How to change to upload all type of file. I have tried many methods. But the result is not getting. Please help me.

My code is given below :-

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageview;
String imagepath;
File sourceFile;
int totalSize = 0;
String FILE_UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.1.3/work/filesharing/4.php";
LinearLayout uploader_area;
LinearLayout progress_area;
public DonutProgress donut_progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uploader_area = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.uploader_area);
    progress_area = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_area);
    Button select_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
    Button upload_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_upload);
    donut_progress = (DonutProgress) findViewById(R.id.donut_progress);
    imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    select_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();



            intent.setType("image/*"); // intent.setType("video/*"); to select videos to upload
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);


        }
    });


    upload_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (imagepath != null) {
                new UploadFileToServer().execute();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select a file to upload.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
       BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger images
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath, options);

    }
}
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

**UploadFileToServer.class**

```
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        donut_progress.setProgress(0);
        uploader_area.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Making the uploader area screen invisible
        progress_area.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Showing the stylish material progressbar
        sourceFile = new File(imagepath);
        totalSize = (int)sourceFile.length();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        Log.d("PROG", progress[0]);
        donut_progress.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0])); //Updating progress
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        String fileName = sourceFile.getName();

        try {

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(FILE_UPLOAD_URL).openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            String boundary = "---------------------------boundary";
            String tail = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            String metadataPart = "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
                    + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"metadata\"\r\n\r\n"
                    + "" + "\r\n";

            String fileHeader1 = "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
                    + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadfile\"; filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"\r\n"
                    + "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
                    + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n";

            long fileLength = sourceFile.length() + tail.length();
            String fileHeader2 = "Content-length: " + fileLength + "\r\n";
            String fileHeader = fileHeader1 + fileHeader2 + "\r\n";
            String stringData = metadataPart + fileHeader;

            long requestLength = stringData.length() + fileLength;
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "" + requestLength);
            connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) requestLength);
            connection.connect();

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.writeBytes(stringData);
            out.flush();

            int progress = 0;
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            BufferedInputStream bufInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
            while ((bytesRead = bufInput.read(buf)) != -1) {
                // write output
                out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                out.flush();
                progress += bytesRead; // Here progress is total uploaded bytes

                publishProgress(""+(int)((progress*100)/totalSize)); // sending progress percent to publishProgress
            }

            // Write closing boundary and close stream
            out.writeBytes(tail);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            // Get server response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Exception
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e("Response", "Response from server: " + result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

 }
```

Comment: here is good example to upload file on server: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically

Comment: @Piyush I want the code in android. How implement the above code where i shown?

Comment: you can check this out : https://gist.github.com/anggadarkprince/a7c536da091f4b26bb4abf2f92926594